# Check the DEC value of a char

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to create a for-loop which checks if a member of my char array is the ASCii value I'm looking for (a=97, d=100, g=103, and so on), and if it is, add 5 to an int value I have, however, my code isn't working but I can't figure out why

```
string str;
cin >> str;
int arrSize = str.size();

char arr[arrSize];
strcpy(arr, str.c_str());

int ans = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
{
    if(arr[i] == 97 || 100 || 103 || 106 || 109){ ans+= 5; }
    else{ ans+= 3; }
}

cout << ans;
```

a gives me 5, but so does every other value (b,c,e,f,h,i...).

Comment: if(arr[i] == 'a' || arr[i] == 'd' || arr[i] == 'g' || arr[i] == 'j'|| arr[i] == 'm'){ ans+= 5; }

It's more readable

Comment: There is no need to copy the string. str[i] will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr[i] == 97 || 100 || 103 || 106 || 109
```

This is wrong. It is equivalent to:

```
(arr[i] == 97) || (100) || (103) || (106) || (109)
```

Is 100 true? Yes, it is. Therefore, everything will be true.

Instead you want:

```
arr[i] == 97 || arr[i] == 100 || arr[i] == 103 || arr[i] == 106 || arr[i] == 109
```

Comment: @matr it works this way for most other languages. If some language has different precendence for `==` and `||` then it'll be treated as `arr[i] == (97 || 100 || 103 || 106 || 109)` so it won't work as you expected too